# Overflow-y on iFrame not showing Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using an iFrame on the following website for the online booking as shown below:

http://www.marandy.com/one2onev2

In Chrome or IE the scroll bar on the y-axis shows as expected, but in Chrome this doesn't seem to show.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
        <div id="main-online-booking">

            <iframe id="main-online-frame" class="booking-dimensions" src="http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

            <div id="main-online-user">

                <a href="#" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Account" id="img-onlinebooking-acc" src="images/account.png" /></a>

                <a href="#" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Guest" id="img-onlinebooking-guest" src="images/guest.png" /></a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
#main-online-booking {

height: 488px;
border-bottom: 6px #939393 solid;
border-left: 6px #939393 solid;
border-right: 6px #939393 solid;
z-index: 4;
background-color: #fff;
}

#main-online-frame {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
frameBorder: 0;
height: 488px;
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working or how I can get this to work as it does in Firefox/IE?

Any help would be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Did you try adding `overflow-y` at the parent and not at the `iframe`?

Comment: Also, `overflow-y:scroll` will be ignored if the `iframe` height fits the container. So, it's an expected result not to see the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

```
<iframe id="main-online-frame" class="booking-dimensions" src="http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Change scrolling="no" into scrolling="yes".

That should do the work.

Be sure to refresh the page, the scrolling will only appear when any of the functions enlarge the content.

Comment: although this worked, it actually shows both Y and X scrollbars, even though I had this set to overflow-x: hidden; & overflow-y: scroll; - I've read somewhere that in chrome it inherits the scroll for both axis if you have one set to scroll and one hidden.

Comment: if scroll bar will display, the page will looking ugly, so define a width property to the iframe is the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding overflow:scroll to #main-online-booking, and adjust the height to your liking in that same style.

The CSS:

```
#main-online-booking {
overflow:scroll;
z-index: 4;
height: 488px; /*adjust this to your desire*/
border-bottom: 6px #939393 solid;
border-left: 6px #939393 solid;
border-right: 6px #939393 solid;
background-color: #fff;
}

#main-online-frame {
frameBorder: 0;
height: 488px; /*adjust this to your desire*/
width: 600px;
}
```

You can check out my jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/e6pPC/10/).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `width` property to iframe.

Ex.

```
<iframe id="main-online-frame" class="booking-dimensions" src="http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="600px"></iframe>
```